# How can I call the function from another python file into a certain file

Tags: python, function, file, import, python-import

I have a function called generate_random() in file a_05, and I'm trying to get it into file mid_file.
I had the code

```
from a_05 import generate_random as gr

gr()
```

But I would get errors like a ModuleNotFoundError: For reference, these files are in the same folder.

Comment: I'm going to need some code to look at. I reproduced this my self and got no error. Please provide us with the function. Are you certain that the file is named `a_05` and the function is named `generate_random`?

Comment: @Goldwave yes, the file is named that and that is the name of the function